# php session does not work

Tags: php, session

I know that there are many questions with the same title. 
I read the most of the but i cant figure out what is wrong.

I have two php files, every one is in  different domain.

I try to pass the `$_SESSION` value from the `index.php` page in one domain to to the `get.php` page that is in other but without success.

Whet echo the  `$Referal` var in the `get.php` file i get no result.

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['origURL'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo $_SESSION['origURL'];
include 'functions.php'; 

?>
```

get.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'inc.php';
$Referal = $_SESSION['origURL'];
echo $Referal; 

?>
```

inc.php

```
<?php
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jerusalem");

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'userclass.php';
require_once 'leedclass.php';
require_once 'sessionclass.php';

?>
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: If the domains are on different web servers, you cannot share the sessions? One way would be to save them in a centralized database and then access through your code.

Comment: You need to specify session save path in php.ini file which should same for both domain

Comment: O.K, great, i didnt knew that sessions cant pass through different domains.  thank you!

Comment: can you display the error?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reason-
1. Check that if session save path is writable 
2. Also check that both files are on same server ,Session will not work on different server , Also check if your domain is with 'www' or without 'www' ,This also effects session .

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the session variable using the `header()`
Like this
`header("Location:your_url?".session_name()."=".session_id());`

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but in that case encryption will help you...

Comment: Doesn't matter.. What if your user user c/p his `URL` on a public board or the URL gets sniffed  by another user on the same router/switch

Comment: OK then tell me 1 think are you redirecting the url on form submit or some other event....?